# Looking up last two entries in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This might be impossible but I hope not. I am trying to pull the last two entries from a column and add them together and then divide by two to get a percentage. These entries are updated daily so the row will change. The new percentage will be in a different worksheet in the same workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(9^99, A:A))+INDEX(A:A, MATCH(9^99, A:A)-1))/2
```

`INDEX(A:A, MATCH(9^99, A:A))` gets the last number in the column.

`INDEX(A:A, MATCH(9^99, A:A)-1)` gets the second to last number in the column.

All that remains is to add and divide by two.

`MATCH(9^99, A:A)` gets the row number in which the last value is found in. It works since it uses 'less than' matching by default and will get the last match that is less than the value `9^99`.

**Note:** In all instances, put the worksheet name before the range. If the worksheet name is, for example `Wk`, and the column is D, then use:

```
'Wk'!D:D
```

---

> I need to select the last 14 entries now

If you have 14 entries, you have to make some small adjustments to the formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(9^99, A:A)-13):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(9^99, A:A)))/2
```

Notice that I added `SUM` at the front, changed the position of the `-` part (with 2 last entries, you subtract 1, with 14, you subtract 13, that is one less) and changed the `+` into `:`.

Comment: Just put the sheet's name before the ranges A:A in this formula, e.g.  `MATCH(9^99,Sheet1!A:A)`

Comment: @Raystafarian All of the ranges in fact need the reference =P Thanks for pointing it out, I missed that part.

Comment: @user301197 You're welcome :)

Comment: Sorry guys, one more question. All of that worked great, but I need to select the last 14 entries now. Help me please.

Comment: @user301197 And still add the 14 and divide by 2?

Comment: so do I need to do the INDIRECT part 14 times with -1 at the end?

Comment: @user301197 I edited my answer! Note that if there are blanks within the last 14 cells, this formula might not work as intended, unfortunately. It will be much longer if it has to ignore blank cells.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, rename "Sheet1" to the sheet you're referencing

`=(SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)),INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1)))/2`

Jerry's solution is less volatile than this one, I'd recommend it.

Comment: +1 but a possible problem might be blank cells. `COUNTA` ignore those =)